# Compute the contraction of a 1-form with a vector field

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

**Question:** Let $\alpha$ be the $1$-form on $\mathbb{R}^3$ given by $\alpha=zdy-ydz$ and let $\mathbb{X}$ be the vector field on $\mathbb{R}^3$ given by $\mathbb{X}=(0,y,-z)$. Compute $i_\mathbb{X}\alpha$

**Answer:** $i_{(0,y,-z)}(zdy-ydz)=i_{(0,y,-z)}(zdy)-i_{(0,y,-z)}(ydz)=zy-y(-z)=2yz.$

Is this answer correct? I feel that I must have done something wrong as I feel there should be more to the question.

I am not familiar with taking the contraction of a one form.

Can you just use the relation: $i_vf^{(j)}=v^j$?

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes that's right, are you familiar with the question? $\beta=xzdx\wedge dz$

Comment: So what is the point of $\beta$, since you are only asking for the pullback of $\alpha$?

Comment: If your asking me, I don't think there is any importance of $\beta$ hence I didn't include it in my question. There was however a $\beta$ used in another part of this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your computation of $i_{\mathbb{X}}\alpha$ is correct. Let me explain some general facts that work on any manifold (at least locally), but keep it restricted to $\mathbb{R}^3$.

First note that a one-form $\alpha$ is a function on vector fields. Any one-form can be written as a linear combination of $dx$, $dy$, and $dz$ where the coefficients are functions of $x$, $y$, and $z$ - another way of saying this is that $\{dx, dy, dz\}$ is a basis for the one-forms. By linearity, in order to understand the value of a one-form on a vector field, it is enough to know the values of $dx$, $dy$, and $dz$ on a vector field. If $V = (v^1, v^2, v^3)$ is a vector field (here the $v^i$ are functions of $x$, $y$, and $z$), then

$$dx(v^1, v^2, v^3) = v^1\qquad dy(v^1, v^2, v^3) = v^2\qquad dz(v^1, v^2, v^3) = v^3.$$

Because of these relationships, one can specify $dx$, $dy$, and $dz$ as the dual basis of the standard basis of vector fields.

What does any of this have to do with contraction? Well, in the case of one-forms $i_{\mathbb{X}}\alpha = \alpha(\mathbb{X})$; i.e. contraction by a vector field is nothing but evaluation of the form on the vector field. Note, in the case of $k$-forms where $k > 1$, contraction is not the same as evaluation.

Comment: Wow, great answer, I was looking for a comprehensive overview of the contraction of $1$-forms so thank-you.

Comment: > Note, in the case of k-forms where k>1, contraction is not the same as evaluation.

I think this is somewhat misleading.  Contracting is **partial application**

Comment: @StevenGubkin: I understand what you're saying, but I don't think it is misleading (after all, partial application is not the same as evaluation), it just isn't as informative as it could be. The choice to say what I did about higher degree forms and nothing more was a pedagogical one. Given that the OP is still coming to terms with contraction in the easiest case (one-forms), I didn't want to confuse them. When the OP learns about contraction of higher degree forms, they will realise that contraction of one-forms coinciding with evaluation is merely a special case of partial application.

Answer (score 1):

$\beta$'s irrelevance notwithstanding, your computation of $\iota_{\mathbb X}\alpha$ is correct. I'm not sure what your final question is supposed to mean.

Comment: Thanks for your confirmation, this is the first time I have computed the contraction of a $1$-form and for some reason had a feeling that I had done something wrong.